# Zsh quote weird behaviour

Tags: zsh

Why is doing :

```
for i in 0 foo 1 'bar t ttt' 2 baz 3 '   ' 4 'qux ' 5 ''; do echo $i; done
```

(Resulting in :

```
0
foo
1
bar t ttt
2
baz
3

4
qux 
5
```

)

Not equivalent to :

```
a="0 foo 1 'bar t ttt' 2 baz 3 '   ' 4 'qux ' 5 ''"
for i in `echo $a`; do echo $i; done
```

which gives :

```
0
foo
1
'bar
t
ttt'
2
baz
3
'
'
4
'qux
'
5
''
```

?

Comment: The single quotes are quoted as part of the double quoted string that you assign to `a`. If you want to get the same output as with the first loop but with a variable, use an array: `a=( 0 foo 1 'bar t ttt' 2 baz 3 '   ' 4 'qux ' 5 '' )`. Also, loop over `$a`, not what `echo` decides to output.

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop iterates over the members of an array, whereas your second loop iterates over a string, which gets split on spaces. If you want the second loop to produce the same output as the first one, you need to declare `a` as an array:

```bsh
a=( 0 foo 1 'bar t ttt' 2 baz 3 '   ' 4 'qux ' 5 '' )
for i in $a; do echo $i; done
```

Or, if you're limited to using a string, you need to split it on shell words (instead of white space) and then remove the single quotes:

```bsh
a="0 foo 1 'bar t ttt' 2 baz 3 '   ' 4 'qux ' 5 ''"
for i in ${(Q)${(z)a}}; do echo $i; done
```